# java regex preferences when multiple matches occur

Tags: java, regex

Hi I'm trying to understand in particular how does the OR operator "|" work in java regex. I'm just starting to use it and most of the things are unclear to me.

Suppose I wish to match fractions and integers, that is to say things of the form 1/2, 12/25, and also things of the form 13, 235, etc.

I have tried these 2 patterns:

```
pattern1 = Pattern.compile("\\d+|\\d+/\\d+"))
pattern2 = Pattern.compile("\\d+/\\d+|\\d+"))
```

In English, pattern1 says "digits OR digits/digits", whereas pattern2 says "digits/digits OR digits".

Now consider this input string:

```
inputStr = "blah... 231/232 blah... 4 blah... 2"
```

For pattern1, I found these matches:

```
[junit] found 231
[junit] found 232
[junit] found 4
[junit] found 2
```

For pattern2, I found these matches:

```
[junit] found 231/232
[junit] found 4
[junit] found 2
```

Now the only difference between pattern1 and pattern2 is the orders of its matched elements. Of course pattern2 is the one I wanted, as it seems to "prefer" a real faction than to take them apart.

So the most important question for me is this:
Is this behaviour reliable/predictable, or is it going to be different for different platforms?

But also just curious... this question too:
I also find it confusing because the operator "OR" should be symmetric with regard to its arguments, like addition. You'd imagine people be worried when 1+2 and 2+1 carries different semantics... is there any reason for pattern1 and pattern2 here to be semantically different?

Comment: Check out the first section: http://www.regular-expressions.info/engine.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`|` isn't just `OR`, it means "match the first thing, *and if that fails*, match the second thing".

Thus, you want to put the fraction first since it's the preferred form.

Comment: For reference, some regexp matchers match `|` greedily, i. e. the longest match. In that case you would not have that problem. I think it's especially *regular expression* matchers (as in those that correspond exactly to the regular languages) that do so.

Answer (score 4):

A more useful regex for your purpose would be `\\d+(/\\d+)?`which mandatorily checks for a group of digits and an optional group formed by a slash followed by digits.

Answer (score 2):

The alternation operator is like a lazy-OR in that it will match the first thing it can.  There are other posts on the topic that help clarify its behavior:

[Java regex alternation operator "|" behavior seems broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515309/java-regex-alternation-operator-behavior-seems-broken)

[Why order matters in this RegEx with alternation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10248776/why-order-matters-in-this-regex-with-alternation)

In general, all regex's work this way...  Except POSIX.  So, portability should not be a concern in Java.

Answer (score 0):

The | is called an alternation, and it gives the ability to list alternatives for a given match, and will stop on the first alternate pattern matched, from left to right.  AFAIK, this is very consistent across all Java versions and the programming languages/tools I've used regexes with:  Java, Perl, Python, PHP, sed.