# Why is regex Pattern matching "|" in the below displayed code?

Tags: java, regex

Ok. I know that i am missing something. I am just not able to find out what I am missing. The below mentioned pattern matches "|" and i don't know why. Can someone please explain. thanks.
I want to match a single character. The character set is {,},[,],|,? etc.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "";
    if (str.matches("[\"|`|+|,|;|<|>|?|\\[|\\]|{|}|']"))
        System.out.println("matches");

}
```

Comment: You say you are surprised that | matches, but you list | in the character set you want to allow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use the `|` sign in the regex, because you're using an array of characters to match to. Basically if you want to match something to `a,b,c or d`, which means that the string can contain any of those letters you can simply do

```
String pattern = "[abcd]*"; // * means they can be repeated, for example "aabdcb"
str.matches(pattern);
```

No need to use the pipe. On the other hand if you want to strictly say that a string is either `a or b` you can use a pattern like

```
pattern = "(a)|(b)"; // matches either "a" or "b"
```

Hope this clears up things a bit for you.

You might want to check out [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to learn more about using pipe in regexes.

Comment: oh sweet lord. I gotto get some rest. Thanks bro.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `[]` to start and end the expression, when it looks like you are using syntax that goes with `()`. The square braces let you list a bunch of characters that match, and `|` is in your list many times. Parentheses set up a grouping inside which you can use `|` to mean "or".

I think the solution for you is to remove those `|`. You don't separate characters inside square braces with anything, you just list them all.

Answer (score 0):

In short, You have given **|** in the [ ] brackets.

Any character within square brackets[ ] will be matched.

Remove all the **|** inside the braces.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up two different ways of specifying alternatives:

- a [character class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html) (`[]`)
- the [alternatives separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515309/java-regex-alternation-operator-behavior-seems-broken) (`|`)

Pick one.