# Java matcher class priority

Tags: java, regex

I have a question about Matcher. If there are two capturing group that can be satisfied, which one will it choose?
Let's say the pattern is `(A|AB|B)`, if matcher is input with `"AB"`, will it satisfy the `A` group then the `B` group or the `AB` group?

Comment: Did you try this example?. It should be simple enough to test.

Comment: It matches the first, not the longest.

See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515309/java-regex-alternation-operator-behavior-seems-broken